# magento2: Category and product page not working properly - Luma Child

Tags: category, category-products

I've created a child theme of the Luma theme with basic theme files. I've default.xml files on the theme layout and web folder (for js and CSS).
All pages are working fine but when I started adding the product, categories and product pages are not working. Category page layout are showing like the attached screenshot.

Can anyone let me know the exact issue as I am new in Magento?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.
It was due to missing `etc/view.xml` in my theme